# Admob is not showing ads on real device after build. Expo React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob, expo

Expo SDK Version: 36.0.0

Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

I use the expo Admob lib to implement AdMob banners and interstitial Ads on my App. When running through expo cli on my emulator it works perfectly. When I use real `adUnitID` it shows a real ad. However, after building the apk file and installing on real devices, the Ads are not showing anymore.

My implementation is quite simple:

```
<AdMobBanner
    bannerSize="mediumRectangle"
    adUnitID={'ca-app-pub-my-key/my-key'}
    onAdViewDidReceiveAd={() => adReceived('success')}
    onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={() => adReceived('err')}
/>
```

`adReceived(arg)` - it’s just a logger, which save results, do I have success request to Google ad server or not.
On real device I have err messages. So, it looks like then app doesn’t have permission to making request to the internet.

I don’t have `permission` section in my `app.json`, and any other specific setting in this file. According to `Configuration with app.json` page - `To use ALL permissions supported by Expo, do not specify the "permissions" key.`

I found on stackoverflow and expo-forum a lot of relevant topics. And no one provided any working solution.

If I should provide some additional information, please specify what I need to add.
If there is a solution to this, which I didn’t find then please add the link.
Let’s help to resolve this question once and forever for all developers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how I fixed the problem
first of all - you can add an argument with error

```
    onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={(errorCode) => console.log(errorCode)}
```

secondly
When I added my apps to the Google Play store and install it from the store, then my app start showing Ad correctly

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://quickappninja.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002693285-Why-aren-t-my-Admob-ads-showing-), there are six reasons. But probably, you did not update your **payment details** or your region has a **slower fill-rate**. Slower fill-rate means, there are less advertisers targeting these markets (in your region or language).